# Warning: require(__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php) when manually installing wordpress on Plesk

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone please help me. I'm trying to manually install WP on Plesk but gets this error.

Warning: require(**DIR**/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\taranawa.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 17

Warning: require(**DIR**/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\taranawa.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\taranawa.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

You must change PHP version to 7.4

Requirements for the latest version of WordPress (https://wordpress.org/download/)

- PHP 7.4 or greater
- MySQL version 5.6 OR MariaDB version 10.1 or greater.
- Apache or Nginx